# Elasticsearch Index Design based on very big nested array (could have more than 300,000 records)

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a following index schema:

```json
PUT index_data
    {
        "aliases": {},
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "Id": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "title": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "data": {
                    "properties": {
                        "FieldName": {
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        "FieldValue": {
                            "type": "text"
                        }
                    },
                    "type": "nested"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Id is a unique identifier. Here data field is an array and it could have more than 300,000 objects and may be more. Is it sensible and correct way to index this kind of data? Or we should change our design and make the schema like following:

```json
PUT index_data
    {
        "aliases": {},
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "Id": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "title": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "FieldName": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "FieldValue": {
                    "type": "text"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In this design, we cant use Id as a document id because with this design, id would be repeating. If we have 300,000 FieldName and FieldValues for one Id, Id would be repeating 300,000 time. The challenge here is to generate our custom id using some mechanism. Because we need to handle both insert and update cases.

In the first approach one document size would be too large so that it could contain an array of 300,000 objects or may be more.
In second approach, we would have too many documents. 75370611530 is the number we currently have. This is the number of FieldNames and FieldValues we have. How should we handle this kind of data? Which approach would be better? What should be the size of shards in this index?

Comment: Update will be an issue. Es doesnot support partial update, an update will reindex the whole document (so all the nested linked data). Take a took at child/parent relationship.

Comment: Good Point, so the second approach would be better right?

Comment: Yes, but keep in mind if you have to query parents / childs conditions are like "join" => for example if you store date / avaibilities in your data fields and you are looking for parents having availabilities between date1 and date2 the query is "expensibe. Your amount of data is huge :),  try 1 shards for 10go, if you need performance for search keep the number of shards small, if you prefer fast update grow up the number of shards. From my experience a big cluster like that need a lot of tuning.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the current mapping is not nested. I assume you would need to be nested as the query seems to be "find value for key = *key1*".

If it is known that 300K objects are expected - It may not be a good idea. ES soft limit is [10K](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-settings-limit.html#:%7E:text=The%20maximum%20number%20of%20nested,Default%20is%2010000%20.). Indexing issues are going to give trouble with this approach in addition to possible slow queries.

I doubt if indexing 75 billion documents for this purpose is useful - given the resources required, though it is feasible and will work.

May be consider RDBMS?